# Using pivot_longer to turn multiple columns into one in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a df `population` that looks something like this (not all columns and rows listed):

```
Region            X1975     X1976     X1977     ...     X2008
National Total    942420    93717     94974             132802           
Bejing            844.4     845.10    860.50            1695         
Tianjin           702.86    706.50    712.87            968.87
Hebei             4913      4943      4998              6989
...
sum               91979     93275     94540             132058
difference        440       441       433               743
```

The columns go from `X1975` to `X2008` and have every year in between. What I need is for the `population` to look like this:

```
Region       Year        Population
Bejing       1975        844.4
Bejing       1976        845.10
Bejing       1977        860.50
Bejing       1978        871.50
```

and on and on for every Region (including National Total, sum, and difference) and for years 2000 and up to not be included. Would like to do this using pivot_longer, but I'm not sure how. This is what I've gotten so far, which does not work.

```
population %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = starts_with( 'X' ), names_to = c( ".value", "year" ), names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])" ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( year = as.integer( year ) ) -> test
```

or

```
population %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = starts_with( 'X' ), names_to = "year", values_to = "population", ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( year = as.integer( year ) ) -> test
```

Thanks!

DATA:

```
dput(population_to_1999)
structure(list(Region = structure(c(21L, 2L, 30L, 11L, 27L, 16L, 
20L, 19L, 12L, 26L, 17L, 34L, 1L, 5L, 18L, 25L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
7L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 28L, 9L, 33L, 31L, 24L, 6L, 23L, 22L, 32L, 29L, 
4L), .Label = c("Anhui", "Beijing", "Chongqing", "Difference", 
"Fujian", "Gansu", "Guangdong", "Guangxi", "Guizhou", "Hainan", 
"Hebei", "Heilongjiang", "Henan", "Hubei", "Hunan", "Inner Mongolia", 
"Jiangsu", "Jiangxi", "Jilin", "Liaoning", "National Total", 
"Ningxia", "Qinghai", "Shaanxi", "Shandong", "Shanghai", "Shanxi", 
"Sichuan", "sum", "Tianjin", "Tibet", "Xinjiang", "Yunnan", "Zhejiang"
), class = "factor"), X1975 = c(92420, 844.4, 702.86, 4913, 2340, 
1737.9, 3282, 2063.9, 2958.1, 1076.72, 5636.12, 3614.47, 4492, 
2297, 2968.5, 6971, 6758, 4408.15, 4991.36, 4858.48, 3201, 496.82, 
2592.59, 6874.7, 2530.95, 2884.29, 169.11, 2692, 1804.02, 337.49, 
327.92, 1154.53, 91979.38, 440.62), X1976 = c(93717, 845.1, 706.5, 
4943, 2373.1, 1769.2, 3311, 2092.6, 3019.4, 1081.3, 5700.76, 
3662.82, 4558, 2351, 3048.2, 7038, 6852, 4466.7, 5056.81, 4921.95, 
3267, 505.15, 2615.57, 6963, 2585.11, 2951.75, 172.4, 2722, 1825.96, 
346.58, 337.93, 1185.8, 93275.69, 441.31), X1977 = c(94974, 860.5, 
712.87, 4998, 2398.4, 1798.1, 3345, 2117.9, 3072.5, 1086.47, 
5765.28, 3707.4, 4628, 2402, 3118, 7099, 6957, 4520.68, 5111.83, 
4985.54, 3329, 516.36, 2628.06, 7031.3, 2640.14, 3024.59, 175.62, 
2751, 1847.46, 356.75, 346.71, 1208.97, 94540.43, 433.57), X1978 = c(96259, 
871.5, 724.27, 5057, 2423.6, 1823.4, 3394, 2149.3, 3129.6, 1098.28, 
5834.33, 3750.96, 4713, 2446, 3182.8, 7160, 7067, 4574.91, 5165.91, 
5064.15, 3402, 528.45, 2635.56, 7071.9, 2686.4, 3091.47, 178.82, 
2779, 1870.05, 364.86, 355.58, 1233.01, 95827.11, 431.89), X1979 = c(97542, 
897.1, 739.42, 5105, 2447.2, 1851.8, 3443, 2184.6, 3168.7, 1132.14, 
5892.55, 3792.33, 4803, 2487, 3229, 7232, 7189, 4632.78, 5223.05, 
5140.5, 3470, 540.3, 2653.69, 7120.5, 2730.99, 3134.79, 182.69, 
2807, 1893.79, 372.02, 364.14, 1255.97, 97116.05, 425.95), X1980 = c(98705, 
904.3, 748.91, 5168, 2476.5, 1876.5, 3487, 2210.7, 3203.8, 1146.52, 
5938.19, 3826.58, 4893, 2519, 3270.2, 7296, 7285, 4684.45, 5280.95, 
5230, 3538, 552.53, 2664.79, 7154.8, 2776.67, 3173.39, 185.28, 
2831, 1918.43, 376.9, 373.72, 1283.24, 98274.35, 430.65), X1981 = c(100072, 
919.2, 760.32, 5256, 2508.8, 1902.9, 3535, 2230.9, 3239.3, 1162.84, 
6010.24, 3871.51, 4957, 2563, 3303.9, 7395, 7397, 4740.35, 5360.05, 
5326.97, 3613, 560.77, 2694.05, 7215.6, 2826.78, 3222.77, 185.96, 
2865, 1941.4, 381.6, 383.38, 1303.05, 99633.64, 438.36), X1982 = c(101654, 
935, 774.92, 5356, 2546, 1941.6, 3592, 2257.6, 3281.1, 1180.51, 
6088.94, 3924.32, 5016, 2620, 3348.3, 7494, 7519, 4800.92, 5452.12, 
5419.35, 3684, 571.38, 2721.69, 7300.4, 2875.21, 3283.1, 189.25, 
2904, 1974.88, 392.79, 393.04, 1315.9, 101153.32, 500.68), X1983 = c(103008, 
950, 785.28, 5420, 2588.4, 1969.8, 3629, 2269.5, 3306, 1194.01, 
6134.99, 3963.1, 5056, 2668, 3394.5, 7564, 7632, 4865.73, 5509.43, 
5501.85, 3733, 580.66, 2738.63, 7336.9, 2901.46, 3330.8, 193.14, 
2931, 1999.84, 392.57, 399.05, 1333.3, 102271.94, 736.06), X1984 = c(104357, 
965, 795.52, 5487, 2631.5, 1993.1, 3655, 2284.5, 3331, 1204.78, 
6171.43, 3993.09, 5103, 2720, 3457.9, 7637, 7737, 4917.75, 5561.32, 
5585.61, 3806, 589.31, 2747.75, 7364, 2931.85, 3372.1, 196.68, 
2966, 2025.88, 401.61, 406.87, 1344.08, 103383.63, 973.37), X1985 = c(105851, 
981, 804.8, 5548, 2673.5, 2015.9, 3686, 2298, 3357, 1216.69, 
6213.48, 4029.56, 5156, 2769, 3509.8, 7711, 7847, 4980.19, 5622.49, 
5670.65, 3873, 597.51, 2768.26, 7419.3, 2972.18, 3418.1, 199.48, 
3002, 2052.89, 407.38, 414.62, 1361.14, 104575.92, 1275.08), 
    X1986 = c(107507, 1028, 814.97, 5627, 2713.5, 2040.7, 3726, 
    2315.3, 3385, 1232.33, 6269.9, 4070.07, 5217, 2820, 3575.8, 
    7818, 7985, 5047.83, 5695.73, 5799.75, 3946, 605.63, 2807.6, 
    7511.9, 3025.86, 3480, 202.49, 3042, 2085.39, 421.12, 424.33, 
    1383.64, 106117.84, 1389.16), X1987 = c(109300, 1047, 828.73, 
    5710, 2758.1, 2066.4, 3777, 2336.4, 3424, 1249.51, 6348, 
    4121.19, 5287, 2875, 3632.3, 7958, 8148, 5120.27, 5782.61, 
    5931.79, 4016, 615.08, 2845.14, 7613.2, 3072.58, 3534, 207.95, 
    3088, 2115.73, 427.9, 435.16, 1406.33, 107778.37, 1521.63
    ), X1988 = c(111026, 1061, 839.21, 5795, 2807.2, 2093.9, 
    3826, 2357.4, 3466, 1262.42, 6438.27, 4169.85, 5377, 2929, 
    3683.9, 8061, 8317, 5184.94, 5915.68, 6066.84, 4088, 626.85, 
    2873.34, 7716.4, 3127.27, 3594, 212.31, 3140, 2148.15, 434.2, 
    444.53, 1426.42, 109483.08, 1542.92), X1989 = c(112704, 1075, 
    852.35, 5881, 2853, 2122.2, 3876, 2395.4, 3510, 1276.45, 
    6535.85, 4208.88, 5469, 2984, 3746.2, 8160, 8491, 5258.83, 
    6013.62, 6204.96, 4150, 639.2, 2897.01, 7803.2, 3171, 3648, 
    215.91, 3198, 2184.86, 440.2, 454.81, 1454.16, 111170.09, 
    1533.91), X1990 = c(114333, 1086, 866.25, 6159, 2899, 2162.6, 
    3917, 2440.2, 3543, 1283.35, 6766.9, 4238, 5661, 3037, 3810.6, 
    8493, 8649, 5439.29, 6110.89, 6347.19, 4242, 662.77, 2920.9, 
    7892.5, 3267.53, 3730.6, 221.47, 3316, 2254.67, 447.66, 465.68, 
    1529.16, 113860.21, 472.79), X1991 = c(115823, 1094, 872.63, 
    6220, 2941.9, 2183.9, 3939, 2459.7, 3575, 1287.2, 6843.7, 
    4269.5, 5744, 3079, 3864.6, 8570, 8763, 5512.33, 6166.33, 
    6527.01, 4324, 674.13, 2938.99, 7947.8, 3314.63, 3782.1, 
    225.03, 3363, 2284.92, 454.43, 473.88, 1554.57, 115250.28, 
    572.72), X1992 = c(117171, 1102, 878.97, 6275, 2979.3, 2206.6, 
    3958, 2474, 3608, 1289.37, 6911.2, 4304.4, 5817, 3116, 3913.1, 
    8610, 8861, 5579.85, 6207.78, 6706.45, 4380, 686.4, 2950.78, 
    7992.2, 3360.96, 3831.6, 228.53, 3405, 2314.19, 461.02, 482.27, 
    1580.63, 116471.6, 699.4), X1993 = c(118517, 1112, 885.89, 
    6334, 3012.6, 2232.4, 3983, 2496.1, 3640, 1294.74, 6967.27, 
    4334.8, 5870, 3150, 3966, 8642, 8946, 5653.48, 6245.58, 6936.69, 
    4438, 701, 2964.92, 8037.4, 3408.69, 3885.2, 232.22, 3443, 
    2345.23, 466.7, 490.86, 1605.26, 117721.03, 795.97), X1994 = c(119850, 
    1125, 890.55, 6388, 3045.2, 2260.5, 4007, 2515.6, 3672, 1298.81, 
    7020.54, 4363.7, 5938, 3183, 4015.4, 8671, 9027, 5718.81, 
    6302.58, 7209.58, 4493, 711.39, 2985.59, 8098.7, 3458.41, 
    3939.2, 236.14, 3481, 2387.25, 474, 503.87, 1632.7, 119053.52, 
    796.48), X1995 = c(121121, 1251.1, 894.67, 6437, 3077.3, 
    2284.4, 4034, 2550.9, 3701, 1301.37, 7066.02, 4389, 6000, 
    3227, 4062.5, 8705, 9100, 5772.07, 6392, 7387.49, 4543, 723.79, 
    3001.77, 8161.2, 3508.08, 3989.6, 239.84, 3513, 2437.95, 
    481.2, 512.38, 1661.35, 120405.98, 715.02), X1996 = c(122389, 
    1259.4, 898.45, 6484, 3109.3, 2306.6, 4057, 2579.1, 3728, 
    1304.43, 7110.16, 4413, 6054, 3261, 4105.5, 8738, 9172, 5825.13, 
    6428, 7569.78, 4589, 734.14, 2875.3, 8215.4, 3555.41, 4041.5, 
    243.7, 3543, 2466.86, 488.3, 521.21, 1689.29, 121365.96, 
    1023.04), X1997 = c(123626, 1240, 899.8, 6525, 3140.9, 2325.7, 
    4077, 2600.1, 3751, 1305.46, 7147.86, 4434.8, 6109, 3282, 
    4150.3, 8785, 9243, 5872.6, 6465, 7779.69, 4633, 743, 2873.36, 
    8264.7, 3605.81, 4094, 247.6, 3570, 2494.2, 495.6, 528.94, 
    1718.08, 122402.5, 1223.5), X1998 = c(124761, 1245.6, 905.09, 
    6569, 3172.2, 2344.9, 4090, 2603.2, 3773, 1306.58, 7182.46, 
    4456.2, 6152, 3299, 4191.2, 8838, 9315, 5907.23, 6502, 7990.03, 
    4675, 752.82, 2870.75, 8315.7, 3657.6, 4143.8, 251.54, 3596, 
    2519.37, 502.8, 536.57, 1747.35, 123411.99, 1349.01), X1999 = c(125786, 
    1257.2, 910.17, 6614, 3203.6, 2361.9, 4103, 2616.1, 3792, 
    1313.12, 7213.13, 4475.4, 6205, 3316, 4231.2, 8883, 9387, 
    5938.03, 6532, 8217.91, 4713, 761.93, 2860.37, 8358.6, 3710.06, 
    4192.4, 255.51, 3618, 2542.58, 509.8, 543.29, 1775, 124410.3, 
    1375.7), X2000 = c(126743, 1363.6, 912, 6674, 3247.8, 2372.4, 
    4135, 2627.3, 3807, 1321.63, 7327.24, 4679.91, 6278, 3410, 
    4148.5, 8997, 9488, 5960, 6562.05, 8650.03, 4751, 788.05, 
    2848.82, 8407.5, 3755.72, 4240.8, 259.83, 3644, 2556.89, 
    516.5, 554.32, 1849.41, 126134.3, 608.7), X2001 = c(127627, 
    1385.1, 913.98, 6699, 3271.6, 2377.5, 4147, 2637.1, 3811, 
    1327.14, 7354.92, 4697.27, 6325, 3440, 4185.8, 9041, 9555, 
    5974.56, 6595.85, 8733.18, 4788, 795.55, 2829.21, 8436.6, 
    3798.51, 4287.4, 262.95, 3659, 2575.24, 523.1, 563.22, 1876.19, 
    126866.97, 760.03), X2002 = c(128453, 1423.2, 919.05, 6735, 
    3293.7, 2378.6, 4155, 2649.4, 3813, 1334.23, 7380.97, 4730.76, 
    6369, 3466, 4222.4, 9082, 9613, 5987.8, 6628.5, 8842.08, 
    4822, 803.13, 2814.83, 8474.5, 3837.28, 4333.1, 266.88, 3674, 
    2592.58, 528.6, 571.54, 1905.19, 127647.32, 805.68), X2003 = c(129227, 
    1456.4, 926, 6769, 3314.3, 2379.6, 4162, 2658.6, 3815, 1341.77, 
    7405.82, 4763.46, 6410, 3488, 4254.2, 9125, 9667, 6001.7, 
    6662.8, 8962.69, 4857, 810.52, 2803.19, 8529.4, 3869.66, 
    4375.6, 270.17, 3690, 2603.34, 533.8, 580.19, 1933.95, 128420.16, 
    806.84), X2004 = c(129988, 1492.7, 932.55, 6809, 3335.1, 
    2384.4, 4173, 2661.9, 3816.8, 1352.39, 7432.5, 4803.48, 6461, 
    3511, 4283.6, 9180, 9717, 6016.1, 6697.7, 9110.66, 4889, 
    817.83, 2793.32, 8595.3, 3903.7, 4415.2, 273.68, 3705, 2618.78, 
    538.6, 587.71, 1963.11, 129272.11, 715.89), X2005 = c(130756, 
    1538, 939.31, 6851, 3355.2, 2386.4, 4221, 2669.4, 3820, 1360.26, 
    7474.5, 4898, 6516, 3535, 4311.2, 9248, 9768, 6031, 6732.1, 
    9194, 4660, 828, 2798, 8212, 3730, 4450.4, 277, 3720, 2594.36, 
    543.2, 596.2, 2010.35, 129267.88, 1488.12), X2006 = c(131448, 
    1581, 948.89, 6898, 3374.6, 2392.4, 4271, 2679.5, 3823, 1368.08, 
    7549.5, 4980, 6593, 3558, 4339.1, 9309, 9820, 6050, 6768.1, 
    9304, 4719, 835.88, 2808, 8169, 3757.18, 4483, 281, 3735, 
    2606.25, 547.7, 603.73, 2050, 130202.91, 1245.09), X2007 = c(132129, 
    1633, 959.1, 6943, 3392.6, 2405.1, 4298, 2696.1, 3824, 1378.86, 
    7624.5, 5060, 6676, 3581, 4368.4, 9367, 9869, 6070, 6805.7, 
    9449, 4768, 845.03, 2816, 8127, 3762.36, 4514, 284.15, 3748, 
    2617.16, 551.6, 610.25, 2095.19, 131139.1, 989.9), X2008 = c(132802, 
    1695, 968.87, 6989, 3410.6, 2413.7, 4315, 2710.5, 3825, 1391.04, 
    7676.5, 5120, 6741, 3604, 4400.1, 9417, 9918, 6110.8, 6845.2, 
    9544, 4816, 854.18, 2839, 8138, 3793, 4543, 287.08, 3762, 
    2628.12, 554.3, 617.69, 2130.81, 132058.49, 743.51)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

Comment: Try `population %>% tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = starts_with( 'X' ), names_to = "Year", values_to = "Population")` . Then `mutate(Year = as.integer(sub("^X(.*$)","\\1",Year)))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you! This also worked: `population %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = starts_with( "X" ), names_to = "year", names_prefix = "X", values_to = "population", ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( year = as.integer( year ) ) `

Comment: what about `reshape(df,2:ncol(df),idvar = "Region",dir="long",split = list(regexp = "X\\d+",include = TRUE))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution that makes use of `num_range` for tidy selection of the columns before the call to `pivot_longer`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df %>% 
  select(Region, num_range("X", 1975:1999)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Region,
               names_to = "Year",
               names_prefix = "X",
               values_to = "Population")

> df_long
# A tibble: 850 x 3
   Region         Year  Population
   <fct>          <chr>      <dbl>
 1 National Total 1975       92420
 2 National Total 1976       93717
 3 National Total 1977       94974
 4 National Total 1978       96259
 5 National Total 1979       97542
 6 National Total 1980       98705
 7 National Total 1981      100072
 8 National Total 1982      101654
 9 National Total 1983      103008
10 National Total 1984      104357
# ... with 840 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
df <- structure(list(Region = c("National", "Bejing", "Tianjin", "Hebei"
), X1975 = c(942420, 844.4, 702.86, 4913), X1976 = c(93717, 845.1, 
706.5, 4943), X1977 = c(94974, 860.5, 712.87, 4998), X2008 = c(132802, 
1695, 968.87, 6989)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

#Code
df2 <- pivot_longer(df,cols = -Region) %>%
  mutate(name=gsub('X','',name)) %>% rename(Year=name)

# A tibble: 16 x 3
   Region   Year    value
   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1 National 1975  942420 
 2 National 1976   93717 
 3 National 1977   94974 
 4 National 2008  132802 
 5 Bejing   1975     844.
 6 Bejing   1976     845.
 7 Bejing   1977     860.
 8 Bejing   2008    1695 
 9 Tianjin  1975     703.
10 Tianjin  1976     706.
11 Tianjin  1977     713.
12 Tianjin  2008     969.
13 Hebei    1975    4913 
14 Hebei    1976    4943 
15 Hebei    1977    4998 
16 Hebei    2008    6989
```